# QThread base class not appearing

Tags: qthread, qt5.7

I've installed Qt 5.7 on Windows (8.1). I'm not getting QThread option (as a base class) while I try to add a new class to a project? What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Wizard to create your class, that's normal: just select, i.e., *QObject*, create your class and in the sources replace *QObject* with *QThread* as base class. Don't forget to include QThread class previously (`#include <QThread>`)